# How to achieve a 2 by 2 layout with empty cells with css grid?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, css-grid

I have a design where the entire page has a 3x3 column layout, however, one area of the page goes from 3 columns to 2, by just having negative space where every 3rd column used to be, like so:

[image]

Even when you add more div elements, like so:

[image]

I'm thinking the way to achieve this is using css grid with grid-areas, however, when uncommenting the two lines below this doesn't seem to work:

```
.inner {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    // grid-template-areas: "c c .";
  > div {
    // grid-area: c;
  }
}
```

Am I going the right way about this or would using Flexbox be more appropriate?

[Link to a Codepen](https://codepen.io/A7DC/pen/VqPJKK?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider an empty element that will take the third column/first row and you will have the needed result:

```css
.inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.inner div {
  background:red;
  height:100px;
}
.inner:after {
  content:"";
  grid-row:1;
  grid-column:3;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class='inner'>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

with more element you can try this:

```css
.inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.inner div {
  background:red;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom:2rem; /*to replace row gap*/
}
.inner:after {
  content:"";
  grid-row:1 / span 50; /*take all the third column*/
  grid-column:3;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class='inner'>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
    <div>
      Hey
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Temani, this works, but I've updated my question with more detail. When there's more divs added, the 2x2 column format still needs to remain. With this solution, it unfortunately breaks.